# Add seperate UIView from nib to Drawer View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have created `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` sample app. When I slide left a new view is appear as the picture shows.

[image]

I want to edit this red view from my nib file. How can I add another UIView from the nib & connect to this `menuDrawer`??

This is my Code

MainViewController.h file

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController{
    UIView *menuDrawer;
}

@property (readonly,nonatomic)UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer_open , *recognizer_close;
@property (readonly,nonatomic) int menuDrawerX,menuDrawerWidth;

-(void)handleSwipe :(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender;
-(void)drawerAnimation;

@end
```

MainViewController.m file

```
@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize menuDrawerWidth,menuDrawerX,recognizer_open,recognizer_close;

-(void)handleSwipe :(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    [self drawerAnimation];
}

-(void)drawerAnimation{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:-5];

    CGFloat new_x = 0;
    if (menuDrawer.frame.origin.x < self.view.frame.origin.x) {
        new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x + menuDrawerWidth;
    }else{
        new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
    }

    menuDrawer.frame = CGRectMake(new_x, menuDrawer.frame.origin.y, menuDrawer.frame.size.width, menuDrawer.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    int statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    menuDrawerWidth = self.view.frame.size.width *0.75;
    menuDrawerX = self.view.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
    menuDrawer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(menuDrawerX, self.view.frame.origin.y+statusBarHeight, menuDrawerWidth, self.view.frame.size.height-statusBarHeight)];


    menuDrawer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    recognizer_close = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    recognizer_open = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    recognizer_open.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    recognizer_close.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_open];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_close];

    [self.view addSubview:menuDrawer];

}
```

Comment: yes. same nib. but separate uiview

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

This is example of making menu drawer in the application.

Hope, it will may help you,

:)

Comment: Do you have a good tutorial about creating MMDrawerController app?? The Documentation is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

Rather than loading the view in code, you should have a nib (storyboard of xib) file for the entire controller. In that xib file you should create all the views that you want to and link them to the controller using IBOutlets. 
If you do this you then would be able to put all the views that you want as children of the red one and all of them will be loaded from the nib.

What you should do:

Even tho the option I said before works, I am guessing you are trying to somehow show a menu within the drawer, or any kind of contect not fully related with the rest of the window. Usually it is better to separate logic in different controllers, so I would create a separated controller to handle the drawer. Just create a new VC in the same storyboard where you create the other one. When the method drawerAnimation is triggered: 
1) Load the VC from the storyboard programmatically
2) Add the VC as a child view controller using (content would be the drawer):

```
   [self addChildViewController: drawerViewController];                 // self is your main controller, and content is the one that handles the drawer view.

   drawerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(blabla..); //
   [self.view addSubview:drawerViewController.view];
   [drawerViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
```

3) Animate it

If you want to completely remove the view at some point you can just remove the entire VC using:

```
   [drawerViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
   [drawerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
   [drawerViewController removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
```

Comment: In my code without using this UIView *menuDrawer, if I can use separate VC as you said is very helpful to me. But I still can't add separate view or VC from nib files to this menuDrawer. I tried your code. But in your code what is "content" & "frameForContentController"? I can't understand them. can you explain me the whole code??

Comment: I have updated the code to make it easier to understand. Remove the nib file that you created and use a storyboard instead. Put the two VC in there. Make the initial view controller the main one and for the drawer, load it from the storyboard in the viewDidLoad method of the main one using: 

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:nameOfYourStoryBoardFile bundle:nil];
 DrawerViewController *drawerController = (DrawerViewCOntroller *)[storyboard DrawerViewControllerIdentifier];

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add your menu drawer view in your MainViewController's nib file. Set correct frame(Which is origin.x is -(width of menu drawer)). Create a outlet for that view in your controller.